# How to arrange RGL 3d plot in grid using tagList from htmltools?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rgl

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38766426/2109289) I have been able to produce `rgl` 3d objects (specifically `scatter3d` from the `car` package) in a loop and output it as html in my `knitr` document. However, I find that the images are displayed in a vertical strip. I would like to tile it, for example using the code from the linked answer, I would like to arrange the images into a 2x2 grid (instead of 4x1 as it is now):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guessed you'd have to create an HTML table and put the `rglwidget()` results into it.  This code does that:

```
browsable(tag("table", 
    tagList(tag("tr", 
        tagList(tag("td", 
                    tagList(rglwidget(width=200))), 
                tag("td",
                    tagList(rglwidget(width=200))))))))
```

but obviously you'd want to work on it to make it usable.

This post:  [htmlwidgets side by side in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950710/htmlwidgets-side-by-side-in-html)  describes a different approach using CSS.

What I'd do instead is use `mfrow3d(2,2)` to put the plots all into one widget, for example

```
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol = 3)
mfrow3d(2,2)
for (i in 1:4)
  plot3d(xyz, col = i)
rglwidget()
```